# Saving pdf file after rotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

Following code opens PDF file, finds where a QR code is located and then rotates the PDF file so that the QR code is located in the top left corner.

The code reads and rotates just fine, but it saves the file using original layout and I would like it to save the file rotated.

```
for (int pg = 0; pg < inputDocument.PageCount; pg++)
{
    QRCodeDecoder decoder = new QRCodeDecoder();
    string workGif = workingFilename.Replace(".pdf", string.Format(".{0}.gif", pg + 1));
    GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb(workingFilename, workGif, pg + 1, 300, 300); // size (last two params) does not seem to have any effect

    using (var fullImg = new Bitmap(workGif))
    {
        var bandImg = fullImg.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);

        //AA THIS SECTION NEEDS TO BE CLEANED UP FOR ACTUAL USE
        Bitmap result = fullImg;
        //top-left
        var bandImg1 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width/2, result.Height/2), fullImg.PixelFormat);

        //top-right
        var bandImg2 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(result.Width / 2, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);

        //bottom-left
        var bandImg3 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);

        //bottom-right
        var bandImg4 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);

        Bitmap[] corners = new Bitmap[] { bandImg1, bandImg2, bandImg3, bandImg4 };
        string QRinfo = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < corners.Length; ++i)
        {
            string tempQRinfo = Process(corners[i]);
            if (tempQRinfo != null)
            {
                QRinfo = tempQRinfo;
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0: break; //already upper left
                    case 1: fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone); break;//upper right: rotate -90
                    case 2: fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);  break;//lower left: rotate 90
                    case 3: fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone); break;//lower right: rotate 180
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (QRinfo == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("QRCode was not found");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(QRinfo);
            Console.WriteLine(QRinfo);
        }

        string[] qcode = QRinfo.Split('/');
        string gid = qcode[qcode.Count() - 1];
        Guid pgGuid = new Guid(gid);
        var ar = dc.Assessments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == pgGuid);
        if (ar != null)
        {
            var p = inputDocument.Pages[pg];
            string opdName = FILESTORELOCATION + pgGuid.ToString() + ".pdf";
            PdfDocument opd = new PdfDocument(opdName);
            opd.Pages.Add(p);
            opd.Close();

            ar.StoragePath = opdName;
            ar.LastUploadedDT = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ar.UploadedByUserID = uploadingUser;
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    File.Delete(workGif);
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to generate a new PDF based off the rotated images.

Comment: @agrothe how can i do this properly with what i have? thanks.

Comment: are you using any particular PDF library?

Comment: @agrothe here is what i am using regarding pdf: PdfSharp, GemBox, com.google.zxing,

Answer (score 1):

Using PDFSharp you can accomplish this. This example shows you how.

```
 var souce = // your rotated image here
 PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
 doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
 XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
 XImage img = XImage.FromFile(source);

 xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
 doc.Save(destinaton);
 doc.Close();
```

Found this from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1348035.aspx/1).

Comment: So my `source` is a bitmap image and `XImage.FromFile()` wants a string passed in. Also for me i break up my file into four sections to find in what section the qrcode is in. i cannot pass in one of those sections because it will only save that part of the section and not the whole file- correct?

Comment: Correct, you will need to reconstruct the image in whatever orientation you need it, save it to a temp location (or use another method that takes a stream, there are several examples on the PDFSharp website).